# How to exit or break from 'for loop' on Arduino C Program

Tags: for-loop, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I'm not new to the programming world, but for last 2 weeks I'm working with Arduino C++. I have a strange problem. In general, I have a 7-segment display that will act as an up counter when the condition is 01, down counter when the condition is 10, 00 for reset to zero, and 11 for stop (pause in that number).

The problem is, when the up or down counter is still counting and I've change the state, the 7-segment is still counting! Besides that, I've printed the status of state when state is changed, but nothing happens. I think maybe there's mistakes in my code, I need some advice from you guys. Here is my code:

*FYI, I've try to use **break**, **return**, also call **loop()**, but nothing happens

*saklar1 = switch1
*saklar2 = switch2

```cpp
#include <SevSeg.h>

SevSeg sevseg;
const int saklar1 = 2;
const int saklar2 = 3;

void setup() {
  byte sevenSegments = 1;
  byte commonPins[] = {};
  byte sevenPins[] = {11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4};
  bool resistor = true;
  sevseg.begin(COMMON_CATHODE, sevenSegments, commonPins, sevenPins, resistor);
  sevseg.setBrightness(90);
    
  pinMode(saklar1, INPUT);
  pinMode(saklar2, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  checking(digitalRead(saklar1), digitalRead(saklar2));
}

void checking(bool saklar1, bool saklar2){
  if (saklar1 == LOW && saklar2 == LOW) {
    setSevSeg(0);
  } else if (saklar1 == LOW && saklar2 == HIGH) {
    for (int i=0; i<=9; i++) {
      setSevSeg(i);
      if (saklar1 != LOW || saklar2 != HIGH) {
        Serial.println("STATE CHANGED"); //THIS LINE IS NOT EXECUTED OR PRINTED
        checking(digitalRead(saklar1), digitalRead(saklar2));
      }
    }
  } else if (saklar1 == HIGH && saklar2 == LOW) {
    for (int i=9; i>=0; i--) {
      setSevSeg(i);
      if (saklar1 != HIGH || saklar2 != LOW) {
        checking(digitalRead(saklar1), digitalRead(saklar2));
      }
    }
  } else if (saklar1 == HIGH && saklar2 == HIGH) {
    delay(100); //Stop
  }
}

void setSevSeg(int num) {
  sevseg.setNumber(num);
  sevseg.refreshDisplay();
  delay(500); //1 detik
}
```

Comment: `if(saklar1!=LOW || saklar2!=HIGH)` how can that ever be true considering it is inside a conditional block with a condition that ensures it is always false:  `else if(saklar1==LOW && saklar2==HIGH)`

Comment: Because I need to check if state is changed from switch input, do you have any advice sir?

Comment: You need to keep track of the **previous** state.

Comment: If you don't want to keep track of the previous state then you need to use digitalRead each time you access the variable because it is only when digitalRead is called that the new value is read.

Answer (score 0):

In the following code, the control exits the for loop when the sensor value exceeds the threshold.

Reference: [https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/control-structure/break]

```
int threshold = 40;
for (int x = 0; x < 255; x++) {
  analogWrite(PWMpin, x);
  sens = analogRead(sensorPin);
  if (sens > threshold) {     // bail out on sensor detect
    x = 0;
    break;
  }
  delay(50);
}
```

Comment: The sensor that I've used is a switch, that typicaly is a digital sensor that will detect the voltage level if there's LOW or HIGH, your answer seems like it is used for analog sensor, but switch is not an analog sensor

Comment: @Amir then use `if(digitialRead(pin)) break;`. A minimum amount of own thinking is required if you want to do any programming. Jonathan probably wanted to encourage you to think and learn something by giving you something that doesn't solve your problem, but shows you how it can be achieved